# configure maven site plugin for multi generational projects

Tags: maven, plugins

I have a company POM, aggregator parent POM, and children.  My company POM has a distributionManagement URL that allows it to deploy a site.  However, when my aggregator and children inherit from it, they are creating incorrect paths.  For example:

```
api-docs/company-pom/1.4-SNAPSHOT/../../procject-webservice/2.0/procject-parent/procject-webservice
```

What is the right way to configure the company POM, and aggregator, so that everyone would end up like this:

```
api-docs/company-pom/1.4-SNAPSHOT/
api-docs/procject-parent/2.0/
api-docs/procject-webservice/2.0/
```

(No, the company POM is not deploying at the same time as the project)